# Talent consent withdrawal in film in Europe

Tags: contract-law, gdpr, privacy

Consider the following scenario of right to erasure in film-making in Europe. Person A makes amateur live-action films, for example theater performances. Person B is in one of those performances and consents to recording and publication verbally or in writing. Later, for whatever personal or professional reason, person B would like to withdraw consent under the GDPR right to be forgotten.

Does person B have the right to erasure and would face and voice count as personal information under GDPR? Does person A have to edit the film to remove, blur, or distort the voice of person B?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> … would face and voice count as personal information under GDPR?

Absolutely.

> Does person B have the right to erasure …

No.

The right to erasure only applies in certain [circumstances](https://ico.org.uk/for-organisations/guide-to-data-protection/guide-to-the-general-data-protection-regulation-gdpr/individual-rights/right-to-erasure/#ib2). While the initial reason for collecting personal data was consent, once it has been incorporated into a film, the processor now has a legitimate interest in the data. The right to erasure does not apply when there is a legitimate interest.

Comment: In an answer about (EU) GDPR, you mention a UK website?

Comment: @DaG UK law on this is still aligned with the GDPR and it’s in English

Comment: Is there a source (even in another language) about that? Present-day relationship between UK and EU don't suggest harmony and agreement. Personally, I don't know about this, but it would be good to double-check.

Comment: @DaG [Here](https://gdpr.eu/right-to-be-forgotten/#:~:text=In%20Article%2017%2C%20the%20GDPR,originally%20collected%20or%20processed%20it.) is an EU funded site on GDPR